# CKEditor 5 balloon editor - need to remove style attribute from all tags or just tags p and span inserted through copy paste

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I use CKEditor 5 balloon editor - I want to remove style attribute from all tags or just tags p and span inserted through copy paste.

I tried this code from documenation:

```
editor.model.schema.register('span', {
    allowAttributes: '',
});
```

or

```
editor.model.schema.register('span', {
    allowAttributes: [],
});
```

Please help to solve.
Thanks in advance.